# What would be a good translation for "throttling"?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

This morning, while chatting with other Spanish.SE users back at [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-tertulia), one of my messages was rejected with the following dialog:

> You can perform this action again in 3 seconds. - retry / edit / cancel

This is a common practice in chat rooms, known as ***throttling***: **forcing a delay on your input when the system thinks that you're going "too fast"** (the word is taken from the concept of [bandwidth throttling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth_throttling)).
This is very annoying to people that type really fast (or tend to send many short messages instead of few long ones), so I said:

> Dios, qué rabia me da el *throttling* que me hace el chat por escribir rápido.

Because I couldn't really think of any Spanish word that conveyed this specific meaning.

So, what Spanish word or expression would fit in the above scenario?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Bandwidth throttling* se traduciría como *limitación de ancho de banda* o alguna cosa similar. Por lo tanto podríamos usar *limitación* en tu ejemplo:

> Dios, qué rabia me da la **limitación** que me pone el chat por escribir rápido.

Es un término muy genérico y sin el contexto no se entendería, si dijeramos:

> Dios, qué rabia me da la **limitación** que me pone el chat.

No quedaría claro a que tipo de limitación nos referimos, así que habría que ponerlo siempre en su contexto, aclarando que es por escribir demasiado rápido. O tal vez usando un apellido: *de envío*, por ejemplo:

> Dios, qué rabia me da la **limitación de envío** que me pone el chat.

Comment: @PeterTaylor cierto. Lo corrijo.

Comment: En apoyo de esta traducción, es la que emplea la primera página de MSDN que he encontrado que hable de throttling y tenga traducción: [versión en inglés](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa578302.aspx) y [en castellano](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ES/library/aa578302.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Intentaría:

> Dios, qué rabia me da la restricción de flujo que me hace el chat por escribir rápido.

pero suena raro…

Otras sugestiones:

> Dios, qué rabia me da el chat al restringirme por escribir rápido.
>
> Dios, qué rabia me da el chat cuando me restringe por escribir rápido.

Comment: Secondo intento: no más traduce *throttling* pero que tál con "Dios, qué rabia me da el chat a restringirme por escribir rápido." ?

Comment: ¡Gracias! Respuesta actualizada.

Comment: Lo que no me queda claro de esta respuesta es cuándo ocurre la restricción. Si es por "escribir rápido" podría entenderse como que ocurre en cualquier momento mientras escribes una frase tecleando demasiado rápido, no únicamente cuando le das al "intro" varias veces en muy poco tiempo.

Comment: @Carlos Es verdad, pero la distinción tampoco existe en la frase inglesa.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo, hasta que no le das al intro no se envía nada. Lo que escribes en el campo de texto está en tu equipo así que no tiene sentido limitarlo antes de enviarlo

Answer (score 3):

Este tipo de filtros se establecen para evitar que un sistema automático inunde el chat de mensajes. Yo haría que la traducción fuera por esos derroteros, tal que así:

> Qué rabia me da el **filtro de mensajes rápidos** del chat.
>   Qué rabia me da el **filtro de mensajes automáticos** del chat.

O, si prefieres algo un poco más jocoso:

> Qué rabia me da el **filtro anti-prisillas** del chat.

Vale que "prisillas" no está en el diccionario de la RAE, pero otros diccionarios más coloquiales [la definen como](http://coloquialmente.com/es/prisillas):

> Persona que hace todo de forma apresurada y descuidada, que siempre está metiendo prisa y va aturullado.

Answer (score 3):

Acabo de caer en que hay un palabra que, al menos en este caso, cuadraría bastante bien:

> **[limitador, ra](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=limitador)**.
>
> 2. m. Dispositivo mecánico o eléctrico que impide sobrepasar ciertos límites de una magnitud. Limitador de velocidad.

Supongo que la mayoria de nosotros conoce esta palabra por el limitador de velocidad que incluyen muchos coches, el cual te deja acelerar solo hasta una determinada velocidad y, si la alcanzas, "[salta](http://dle.rae.es/?id=X6IXCPw#NJyCC5D)" (se activa) y no te deja ir más rápido. En algunos casos, también te avisa con una lucecita, o mensaje en el ordenador de a bordo (si lo tiene).

Usando un símil con lo anterior, creo que una buena traducción para "hacer *throttling*" seria decir:

> Dios, qué rabia me da cuando me **salta el limitador** del chat por escribir rápido.

Comment: Cuando leo lo de "escribir rápido" me da la sensación, al igual que me pasó en el chat, de que el filtro salta cuando tecleas muy rápido la frase que estés escribiendo, no cuando pulsas la tecla "intro" varias veces en muy poco tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la palabra que buscas es "[latencia](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=latencia)".

> Tiempo que transcurre entre un estímulo y la respuesta que produce, y, en particular, lapso entre el momento en que se contrae una enfermedad y la aparición de los primeros síntomas.

Esta es la definición de la RAE pero se utiliza mucho en las telecomunicaciones.

Comment: Yo entendería el uso de "latencia" si desde que se envía un mensaje hasta que llega al servidor se produce un retraso considerable. Creo que no es aplicable en este caso, ya que el "throttling" no es un retraso o latencia, es un límite de tiempo autoimpuesto.

Comment: Si, veo que había entendido mal el concepto.